# Como puedo usar variables en un selector en Node JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, selectores, puppeteer

Esta es mi primer consulta, llevo un tiempo breve en la programación en node.js y estoy teniendo dificultades con un código. Lo que quiero hacer es, mediante tomar la fecha del día de hoy, ingresarla a un selector para poder realizar click en un calendario de una pagina.

Es decir, por ejemplo el día de hoy es 7/1/2021. Me interesa quedarme con el 7. Luego ese 7 lo concateno con el resto del string que preciso en el selector. Esto me queda guardado en una constante de esta forma:

```
   const fecha= #cell7fecha_ida
```

El selector que preciso clickear es

```
'#cell7fecha_ida'
```

es decir (si lo coloco manualmente) seria

```
await page.click ('#cell7fecha_ida')
```

y esto selecciona la fecha 7 en el calendario.

Lo que intente fue la siguiente linea

```
await page.click (fecha)
```

pero devuelve el siguiente error:

(node:7932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: #cell7fecha_ida

Como puedo lograr agregar las comillas simples o vincular mi variable al selector?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda desde ya.

Comment: Según el error, parece que no está encontrado ese nodo, ¿quizás aún no se ha renderizado? Por otro lado, no te haría falta añadir las comillas. En la variable `fecha` ya están implícitas, por ser una cadena.